# Using CrawlDbReader to read Nutch Crawl Data

Tags: nutch, web-crawler

I am using nutch 1.4 to implement a focused crawler. Can anyone tell me how to use the nutch **CrawlDbReader, LinkDbReader** and **SegmentReader APIs** in my **JSP** program so that I can create custom UI for my project.
Specifically, I need to issue commands like **readdb**, **readseg** etc to the crawl data and get the output through a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there something special with these APIs that make this more than "pass data from server to client" issue?
You can use the APIs to get the data. Just look how they are used by nutch.sh, and how the main() is built and do something similar. Then pass the data to the client wither by XML or by JSON or any other way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But once I tried creating a CrawlDbReader object and tried to access its methods. Tried to do exactly what its main() function does. but some classes from some org.hadoop.xxxx package were not accessible from my program... any clue ???

Comment: Check your classpath. You should add hadoop jar to the project build. Nutch for sure has it..

Comment: Ya got it.. Infact I was using another eclipse nutch project in the build path. Now I ve added the hadoop jar. It is accessible now. Thanks..